# ApacheBeam KafkaIO - read messages from unbounded source and terminate pipeline

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

Which ways should be used for reading from Kafka topic via KafkaIO read() for reading all messages and terminate pipeline after that? Is `withCheckStopReadingFn(function)` suitable for that? Are there any approaches?

Comment: Here is helpful info, because you indicated that you are disappointed by not having an answer yet https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers